# How to prevent the RPM from freezing?

Tags: freeze, redhat-enterprise-linux, rpm

I've tried to install several things using redhat's RPM, but every time I try it freezes when the progress bar arrives to "Processing Headers"

I've tried rebuilding the rpm's database

```
rpm --rebuilddb
```

It rebuilds, but still freezes when I try to install something else. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you provide an example command that freezes?

Comment: It happens when I double click any *.rpm file

Comment: Try running "rpm -vi some_rpm.rpm" in a terminal as root (or with sudo) and update your question with the output (if it's useful...).

Comment: Please post the the output of the following:

    rpm -Uvh --verbose package.rpm